# How intermediaries can improve successful connection rate(WebSockets)

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket

I started working with Web Sockets and found [that link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772739(v=vs.85).aspx) and it's saying someting I just can't understand:

> When proxies or network intermediaries are present, there is a higher probability that secure connections will be successful, as intermediaries are less inclined to attempt to transform secure traffic.

So lets assume there are no intermediaries present, what then, who inclined to transform my secure traffic?

I know about `Sec-WebSocket-Key` and `Sec-WebSocket-Accept`, so is it `Sec-WebSocket-Key` that can be manipulated, but again why would data be manipulated at first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intermediaries do not improve connection rate. Maybe you misread that sentence (could be a language barrier).

HTTPS improves connection rate *when intermediaries are present*. In particular, old HTTP proxies might not know what websockets are and mistake such traffic for regular HTTP. They might then accidentally interfere.

With HTTPS, proxies do not have access to the contents of the connection so they *cannot* do anything.